# Provide custom gradient to drake::MathematicalProgram

Tags: drake

Drake has an interface where you can give it a generic function as a constraint and it can set up the nonlinearly-constrained mathematical program automatically (as long as it supports AutoDiff). I have a situation where my constraint does not support AutoDiff (the constraint function conducts a line search to approximate the maximum value of some function), but I have a closed-form expression for the gradient of the constraint. In my case, the math works out so that it's difficult to find a point on this function, but once you have that point it's easy to linearize around it.

I know many optimization libraries will allow you to provide your own analytical gradient when available; can you do this with Drake's MathematicalProgram as well? I could not find mention of it in the MathematicalProgram class documentation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but I admit we haven't provided helper functions that make it pretty yet.  Please let me know if/how this helps; I will plan to tidy it up and add it as an example or code snippet that we can reference in drake.

Consider the following code:

```
from pydrake.all import AutoDiffXd, MathematicalProgram, Solve

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, 'x')

def cost(x):
    return (x[0]-1.)*(x[0]-1.)

def constraint(x):
    if isinstance(x[0], AutoDiffXd):
        print(x[0].value())
        print(x[0].derivatives())
    return x

cost_binding = prog.AddCost(cost, vars=x)
constraint_binding = prog.AddConstraint(
    constraint, lb=[0.], ub=[2.], vars=x)
result = Solve(prog)
```

When we register the cost or constraint with `MathematicalProgram` in this way, we are allowing that it can get called with either `x` being a `float`, or `x` being an `AutoDiffXd` -- which is simply a wrapping of [Eigen's AutoDiffScalar](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1AutoDiffScalar.html) (with dynamically allocated derivatives of type `double`).  The snippet above shows you roughly how it works -- every scalar value has a vector of (partial) derivatives associated with it.  On entry to the function, you are passed `x` with the `derivatives` of `x` set to `dx/dx` (which will be 1 or zero).

Your job is to return a value, call it `y`, with the value set to the value of your cost/constraint, and the derivatives set to `dy/dx`.  Normally, all of this happens magically for you.  But it sounds like you get to do it yourself.

Here's a very simple code snippet that, I hope, gets you started:

```
from pydrake.all import AutoDiffXd, MathematicalProgram, Solve

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, 'x')

def cost(x):
    return (x[0]-1.)*(x[0]-1.)

def constraint(x):
    if isinstance(x[0], AutoDiffXd):
        y = AutoDiffXd(2*x[0].value(), 2*x[0].derivatives())
        return [y]
    return 2*x

cost_binding = prog.AddCost(cost, vars=x)
constraint_binding = prog.AddConstraint(
    constraint, lb=[0.], ub=[2.], vars=x)
result = Solve(prog)
```

Let me know?

Comment: Oh, and we do have some helper functions for initializing autodiff from matrices, etc, here: https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.autodiffutils.html

Comment: Great! That's just what I was looking for. Thanks!